# Code failure when building project with gulp and uplift-js

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am geting to build my project with gulp and uglify-js but it fails and can’t build. And I can’t find what is wrong with this small code snippet.

**Function:**

```
function getGPSLocation() {
        var unregisterHandler = window.bridge.on('gps_location', (parameters)=> {
            $('#gps_token').html("Longitude: " + parameters.longitude + " <br /> Latitude: " + parameters.latitude)
        })
}
```

**Error:**

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

**Error log:**

```
        events.js:160
                throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                ^
    Error
            at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1545:18)
            at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1553:11)
            at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2092:9)
            at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2100:9)
            at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2106:9)
            at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2633:9)
            at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2795:19)
            at expr_ops (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2830:24)
            at maybe_conditional (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2835:20)
            at maybe_assign (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2859:20)
            at maybe_assign (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2867:32)
            at expression (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2878:20)
            at expr_list (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2644:24)
            at subscripts (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2778:30)
            at subscripts (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2755:20)
            at subscripts (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:2755:20)
    Eriks-MacBook-Pro:nat5 erik$
```

Comment: show line no.160

Comment: it is this function that fails gulp. And its this line "var unregisterHandler = window.bridge.on('gps_location', (parameters)=> {"

Comment: Could you please add full error print in detail..

Comment: Just updated the question with the error log

Comment: Any ide? I am thinking its this part   (parameters)=> {    that the gulp does not recognizing